# ssh hangs after successful authentication on command prompt, powershell and wsl2 but not PuTTY

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, openssh, wsl2

## The Issue

SSH connection hangs after a successful login when using Command Prompt or WSL2 on my local machine. However, the same SSH connection works without any issues when using PuTTY. I am **able to see the intro message** after logging in but **not the shell prompt**. This only happens with a specific server. Surprisingly it succeeds with other client machines.
[image: screenshot showing how ssh hangs after successfull login on windows and wsl2]

## Current Environment

- Windows 10 v10.0.19045.2965
- **Windows SSH version**: `OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2`
- **WSL2 SSH version**: `OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 1.1.1f`

## What I tried so far

- Disabled GSSAPIAuthentication: `ssh -T -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no user@host` which worked once but failed with other attempts.
- Changed SSH port at the remote server
- Disabled DNS reverse lookup on the SSH server by setting `UseDNS no` in the SSH server configuration file (located at /etc/ssh/sshd_config).

It's puzzling that PuTTY works fine, but the native SSH clients on my local machine encounter this problem consistently.

Answer (score 2):

The `ssh` command used to connect was `ssh -T user@host`.

The `-T` flag is explained in the ***man*** to be for:

> Disable pseudo-tty allocation

This basically means the exact issue you were having, it's meant to be used ([see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17907289/5518385)) when cases when you specifically do not want an interactive shell (where you can enter commands manually.)

This is probably just unneeded in your case (copied and pasted from something...) and removing it will make the `ssh` work as expected with an interactive shell. Just use:

```
ssh user@host
```